# Maya Python: Can`t adjust list item while for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, maya

I need to update a list inside a *for loop*.

I have some objects in the scene and need to delete some of them if they match an if condition. These objects have children and I need to remove from children names object that was recenеly deleted from the scene and list as well.

Example:

`name2` - an object I need to delete

`name1|name2|name3` - child of `name2`

`name1|name3` - name of `name3`, after `name2` was deleted

```
listA = [u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|C',
      u'|Trunk|Branch_ext',
      u'|Trunk|Branch|A',
      u'|Trunk|Branch|B',
      u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|Branch|D',
      u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|Branch|E',
      u'|Trunk']

for obj in listA:
print '================',obj
print 'list length = {}'.format(len(listA))
trashBin = []
listAUpd = []
shortName  = obj.split('|')[-1] # A, B, C, Branch_ext  etc

objToDelete = 'Branch_ext'

# collect match objects to trashBin
if objToDelete in shortName:
    trashBin.append(obj)


if trashBin:
    # remove trashBin items form list_A
    res = list(set(listA) - set(trashBin))
    listA = res

    # remove deleted object names from objects path
    for item in listA:
        if objToDelete in item:
            listAUpd.append(item.replace('|'+ objToDelete + '|', '|' ))
        else:
            listAUpd.append(item)

    listA  =  listAUpd
    print listA

print 'list length = {}'.format(len(listA))
```

This returns:
[image]

Expecting:
[image]

Comment: Hello Andrew. Please don't post text as an image. This makes in inaccessible to search engines and many people with disabilites, just to name a few of the many drawbacks. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Neuron, In my case text was posted as an image because has to any sense in terms of programming. But any way i will keep your advice in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.. is looks as if you simply want to manipulate some strings. Can't you simply do something like this:

```
listA = [u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|C',
  u'|Trunk|Branch_ext',
  u'|Trunk|Branch|A',
  u'|Trunk|Branch|B',
  u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|Branch|D',
  u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|Branch|E',
  u'|Trunk']

objToDelete = "Branch_ext"
listB = []
for element in listA:
    clean = element.replace("|"+objToDelete, "")
    if len(clean) > 0:
        listB.append(clean)
```

Comment: Hi, haggie! First of all, thank you for your advise. Unfortunately the question: is it possible to change list items while you runing through the list with this items via for loop. I guess it is not possible, Atleast in python. 
I now there are lots of solution options how to remove item from list. 
But I need to do this on fly while not living for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it within the loop, there are a few ways but the clearest is as follows (using haggi krey's example, but based on your expected result):

```
listA = [u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|C',
  u'|Trunk|Branch_ext',
  u'|Trunk|Branch|A',
  u'|Trunk|Branch|B',
  u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|Branch|D',
  u'|Trunk|Branch_ext|Branch|E',
  u'|Trunk']

objToDelete = "Branch_ext"

for i in range(len(listA)):
    listA[i] = listA[i].replace("|" + objToDelete + "|Branch", "|Branch")

print listA
```